# Error in Ionic2 when I clone project from a repository on other computer

Tags: android, cordova, oauth-2.0, ionic2, google-plus

I made a project in ionic2. It is a login with google provider. I followed this [tutorial](http://docs.ionic.io/services/auth/google-native.html).

The application works fine in the computer where it was developed. I cloned the project in another computer to work in team. And I ran these commands.

- npm install
- ionic serve
- ionic platform add android
- ionic run android

Basically I didn't modify anything in the project. I just want to run it. The project builds successfully, but when you try to log-in you get this error in console:

```
04-05 15:39:18.971 17869-17869/com.company.ionic.carpool D/CordovaActivity: Resumed the activity.
04-05 15:39:18.987 17869-17869/com.company.ionic.carpool D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 79205 : EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): 12501
04-05 15:39:18.987 17869-17869/com.company.ionic.carpool I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(79205)] "EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): 12501", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (79205)
04-05 15:39:18.987 17869-17869/com.company.ionic.carpool D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 79210 : ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
04-05 15:39:18.987 17869-17869/com.company.ionic.carpool I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(79210)] "ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (79210)
04-05 15:39:18.992 17869-17869/com.company.ionic.carpool D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 79211 : Error: Uncaught (in promise): 12501
                                                                                      at new Error (native)
                                                                                      at Error.v (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:4864)
                                                                                      at s (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:4289)
                                                                                      at s (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:4112)
                                                                                      at file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:4652
                                                                                      at t.invokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:10284)
                                                                                      at Object.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:38157:37)
                                                                                      at t.invokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:10258)
                                                                                      at e.runTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:7637)
                                                                                      at i (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:3707)
```

I have checked the integrity of all packages and dependencies in the project. I am not able to fix this issue. Does anyone have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: i have the same issue

Comment: can you run `ionic serve` ?

Comment: Yes I can, but the log-in  doesn't work because the method that I used for authenticication is native from Ionic

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow below steps hence you have changed the development environment.

**Step 1:** Remove platform

```
ionic platform rm android
```

**Step 2:** Add platform

```
ionic platform add android
```

**Step 3:** Build

```
ionic build  android
```

**Step 4:** Run

```
ionic run android --device
```