# Blank Screen - Android Studio - E/Web Console: ERROR at file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:1362

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic3

I try to run an empty app (ionic 3) with Android Studio to see why I have a blank screen when I run my app. 
And I have an error that I can't resolve : ***E/Web Console: ERROR at file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:1362***

Ionic info :

```
global packages:

@ionic/cli-plugin-proxy : 1.3.0
@ionic/cli-utils        : 1.3.0
Cordova CLI             : 7.0.1
Ionic CLI               : 3.3.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.3.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.0
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.3.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.10.2
OS         : Windows 10
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
```

I also encountred the error :
***On devices with API level below 21, a full build is required if the app is not running.***

And my phone is an Android 4.1.2 and it has a 16 API and I don't know what is a full build ?

Or:

***Instant Run performed a clean build and install since the installation on the device does not match the local build on disk.***

Someone know how to resolve my problem ?

Thanks in advance ! 
Caroline

Comment: I am not sure but you can try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241382/error-in-ionic2-when-i-clone-project-from-a-repository-on-other-computer

Comment: I followed these steps and the error still persists (ionic platform rm android --> ionic platform add android --> ionic build android --> ionic run android --device)

Comment: AFAIK ionic supports android 4.4 above for anything to 4.0 you need to install [crosswalk](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview)

Comment: It works ! Thanks !!!